# Get combined data about two players from a table with game matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with matches, each row containing two foreign keys, each one referencing a player from a separate table with players.

How can I select data so that it returns complete data of both players in a single row, like their name and surname?

```
SELECT * FROM Matches
JOIN Players ON Matches.Player1_ID=Players.Player_ID
JOIN Players ON Matches.Player2_ID=Players.Player_ID
```

This doesn't work

Comment: Use different table aliases, e.g. `JOIN Players p1 ON Matches.Player1_ID=p1.Player_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set aliases of table using **as**, and then **join**.

```
SELECT Matches.*, Ps1.*, Ps2.* FROM Matches
JOIN Players as Ps1 ON Matches.Player1_ID=Ps1.Player_ID
JOIN Players as Ps2 ON Matches.Player2_ID=Ps2.Player_ID
```